# SQLite error: near "?": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I am getting error message "near "?": syntax error" randomly while
executing the query "SELECT [record] FROM [ac_contacts_cache] LIMIT 0,
3".

Table schema:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
[ac_contacts_cache] (
[record] TEXT NOT NULL
)

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: randomly as in "sometimes, sometimes not, for the same query"? Also, are you using the sqlite command line or some language binding?

Comment: I am getting this sometimes only and getting this for the same query as I am not firing any other SELECT stmt against this table. I am using C api.

Comment: Before I try to answer,

What is your intent of - LIMIT 0, 3?

Is it to only show 3 records?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get LIMIT to work in MS SQL with no luck.  Is this a MySql Command?

Anyhow, try this.

```
SELECT TOP 3 [record] FROM [ac_contacts_cache]
```

Now for your create table.  I have tested both code out just to make sure this works, and  is working in SQL server and is basic sql so should be fine in SQL Lite.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TestTable') AND type in (N'U'))
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TestTable(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [text] NOT NULL ,
    [LastName] [text] NOT NULL)
```

The first line, if you do a SELECT * FROM sys.objects, you can get a good idea of whats going on.  Your simply just retrieving all of the tables on the system, and looking for the one your about to create (Specified in the Where clause, 'TestTable').  If its not created, we move on to our next statement, the Create Table.

You were pretty much dead on here.  So I'm sure you can tell whats going on!

Good luck!

Comment: Did you reply to the wrong question?  This answer has nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: @M.Wires This is testing my memory coming back to a year old question.  But I think I was just saying this is the syntax for creating a table if it does not exist.  I did this because I thought SQLLite did not support the LIMIT clause.  So I showed him how to do it without the LIMIT clause.  After I saw his comment that it was working sometimes, I decided not to update my answer because it can not be the Limit clause if it works sometimes.